# Add hash argument or string argument in a method to a hash (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, methods, hash, arguments

If the argument "entry" to the method add is a hash I need to add it to the :entries hash. If "entry" is a string "entry" needs to be set as a key in the hash and its value to nil. I have a solution below but is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
class Test
    attr_accessor :entries

    def initialize
        @entries = {}
    end

    def add(entry)
        if entry.is_a?(Hash)
          entry.each do |word, definition|
            @entries[word] = definition
          end
        else
          @entries[entry] = nil
        end
    end
end

@test = Test.new
@test.add("the")
#{"the" => nil}
@test.add("the" => "one")
#{"the"=>"one"}
```

Comment: maybe you can set  "@entries" to be Hash.new(nil), so the value of @entries with any key will be nil, then you add entry just judge whether entry is a Hash, and merge it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored the code:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :entries

  def initialize
    @entries = {}
  end

  def add(entry)
    entry.is_a?(Hash) ? @entries.merge!(entry) : @entries[entry] = nil
  end
end
```